# SQL Double NOT IN vs COUNT

Tags: mysql

I need to make a Query that gives me the RefC of the clients that have all ordered at least one type of product using both count and double not in. The count statement is:

```
SELECT NomC, RefC
FROM client NATURAL JOIN commande NATURAL JOIN detail NATURAL JOIN PRODUIT
WHERE TypeP IN ("clou", "cheville", "planche")
GROUP BY NomC
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TypeP) = 3;
```

I'm having trouble coming up with the double "NOT IN" equivalent, and understanding the overall logic behind it and also: Why can't I use NOT EXISTS in this case? Any help is appreciated
[Here is a schema of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21UuH.png)

Comment: You should really execute your queries, it helps a lot with learning sql. This query will neither actually execute (incorrect use of `"`, select/group by column-mismatch for mysql >=5.7), nor would it give the desired resultset ("ordered at least one type", unique RefC's in case you would have non-unique names) or (only) the expected result columns ("RefC"). Also, you can use `not in` whereever you can use `not exists`, so this is just what your teacher wants from you. So use `not exists` if you can do it, and rewrite it to `not in` afterwards (by pushing the dependent column outside).

Comment: First of all I suggest never ever to use natural joins. It can make your query crash when some day someone adds a column to a table that happens to have the same name as a column in another table. Then, when using several tables, qualify your columns. Best would be to use table aliases (e.g. `FROM Client c`) and use these as qualifiers (e.g. `c.NomC`). At last: you should use standard quotes for string literals, which is the single `'`, not the double `"`. Also: Is NomC guaranteed to be unique? It would be more natural to group by RefC, which seems to be the client table's primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same query with three IN clauses. You can also use `EXISTS` (you can always use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`). You cannot use `NOT EXISTS` for what is it you would look for?

```
SELECT NomC, RefC
FROM client 
WHERE RefC IN 
(
  select c.refc
  from commande c
  join detail d on d.refcom = c.refcom
  join produit p on p.refp = d.refp
  where p.typep = 'clou'
)
AND RefC IN 
(
  select c.refc
  from commande c
  join detail d on d.refcom = c.refcom
  join produit p on p.refp = d.refp
  where p.typep = 'cheville'
)
AND RefC IN 
(
  select c.refc
  from commande c
  join detail d on d.refcom = c.refcom
  join produit p on p.refp = d.refp
  where p.typep = 'planche'
);
```

The `COUNT` query is faster than this (because the tables don't have to be read again and again) and easier to read and maintain.

But as Solarflare has mentioned in the request's comments: These queries don't look for "clients that have all ordered at least one type of product", but for clients that have ordered all three products.